# Why is this program in c# not working?

Tags: c#

I need to examine whether is the given number `x` divisible with the smallest number:

```
int x, a, b, c,min;

x = Convert.ToInt32(tbx.Text);
a = x / 100;
b = (x / 10) % 10;
c = x % 10;
a = min;

if (b < min) 
    b = min;

if (c < min) 
    c = min;

 if ((x % min) = 0)
      lbl_solution.Text = "number is divisible";
 else
      lbl_solution.Text = "number is not divisible";
```

How can I fix this error?

> *cannot implicitly convert int to bool*

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?, you are not returning true or false in the IF either.

Comment: Don't you want `(x% min) == 0` instead?

Comment: On which line you get this error? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: And please write a better title. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/writing-a-good-title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your first mistake is in this line:

```
if ((x % min) = 0)
```

you have to use `==` like this:

```
if ((x % min) == 0)
```

the sekond mistake is: the variable `min` isn't inizualized...

```
int x, a, b, c;
int min = 2;

x = Convert.ToInt32(tbx.Text);
a = x / 100;
b = (x / 10) % 10;
c = x % 10;
a = min;

if (b < min) 
    b = min;

if (c < min) 
    c = min;

if ((x % min) == 0)
    lbl_solution.Text = "number is divisible";
else
    lbl_solution.Text = "number is not divisible";
```

Comment: I don't think this is the case. Because `x % min` returns `int` and will be like `5 = 0` and in such a case, error message should be `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer` not `cannot implicitly convert int to bool`

Comment: @SonerGönül no. it will give you that error if you use `(x % min) = 0;` itself. but since it is used in a place where a boolean value expected it tries to convert the result of `(x % min) = 0` to bool hence the error

Comment: @Selman22 Yes, it will give _cannot implicitly convert.._ message **first** then _The left-hand side of an assignment.._ message.

Answer (score 1):

thanks you for helping me very much this is the corect code i made thank to you

```
        int x, a, b, c, min;
        x = Convert.ToInt32(tbx.Text);
        a = x / 100;
        b = (x / 10) % 10;
        c = x % 10;
        min=a;
        if (b < min) 
        b = min;
        if (c < min) 
        c = min;
        if ((x % min) == 0)
           lbl_solution.Text="number is divisible";
        else
            lbl_solution.Text="number is not divisible";
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like the problem is that line;

```
(x % min) = 0
```

`x % min` return an `int` value, not a *variable*. For example it will be `5 = 0`;

That means you will get 2 compile time error in this case;

- Cannot implicitly convert int to bool. (Because `if` statement expects [boolean expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_expression))
- The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer.

Strongly suspect you just want to check your `x` divided by `min` without any reminder. If so, you need to use [equality operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) instead of [assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) like;

```
if ((x % min) == 0)
```

And C# compiler doesn't let you use uninitialized variables. In your case, you try to use `a` and `min` variables without initialize them.